# Causal system giving a non-causal output?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing, planar-graphs

I have just written a Python code ploting DFT's using the **convolution product**:

$$y[t] = u[k] * h[k] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} u[k] h[t-k]$$

I'll take a high resolution so the graph is more precise. Here is a simple example,for $h(t) = \delta(t)$ and $u(t) = \sin(t)\nu(t)$:

[image: Matplotlib]

So far, so good. The causal system gives a causal answer.

Yet, for $h(t) = \nu(t) - \nu(t-6)$, I obtain this graph:

[image: Matplotlib 2]

The causal signal gives a non-causal answer. **Indeed, $y(t)$ is not equal to $0$ for $t<0$** How is it possible ? Maybe is it a mistake from my code ?

Comment: Yes this is a problem in your code. The output should also be casual. My first guess would be that you used $h[k-t]$ instead of $h[t-k]$ in the convolution formula.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on your idea. You were right ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As cleverly suggested by @AndreasLenz, I wrote $k-t$ instead of $t-k$ in the convolution formula:

```
new_h_expression = ""
        for char in h_expression:
            if char == 't':
                new_h_expression = new_h_expression + "k-" + str(t) # here!
            else:
                new_h_expression = new_h_expression + char
```

It is now corrected and the new graph is causal as expected:

[image: Matplotlib]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can accept the answer, so that the question will appear solved

Comment: A self-answer can only be accepted 2 days after being posted